# When working with stateless objects, is there still a performance benefit to marking them const?

Tags: c++, performance, constants, stateless

Among other things, one reason for liberal use of const that I've seen is that, by ensuring that the value won't change, the compiler can more effectively optimize the resulting code. This seems reasonable (but I've also heard that the benefits of this are somewhat minimal).

In any case, would be same be true when working with stateless classes / objects? Could you reasonably expect even a minor speedup from marking stateless objects const, or are today's compilers good enough to recognize statelessness, and optimize for it regardless of whether its marked const or not?

Feel free to answer either in terms of specific compilers, or compilers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "stateless" object must be one with no member variables.  A `const` method simply means that the implicit `this` pointer is `const`.  But if you have no member variables, `this` is only useful to call member functions, and its `const`ness just determines which overload will be called (presumably you'd not overload member functions on `const` when there is no state to mutate).  So we should not expect (but might still discover!) any optimization difference when there is no state to modify, and when all the member functions called through `this` (if it's even a polymorphic class) will be `const` anyway.

Of course, the most important thing to consider in optimization is your specific use case, with your specific compiler, on your specific platform.  Only then will you know for sure if any of this matters.

Answer (score 1):

> are today's compilers good enough to recognize statelessness, and optimize for it regardless of whether its marked const or not?

There's nothing to optimise! You have no data access, so the object being `const` is 100% meaningless.

Comment: My thought was that, stateless objects could have method calls inlined (or possibly even evaluated at compile time).

Comment: @Kevin: They already will be where possible. Marking a member function of a class with no members `const` will make literally zero difference, because by definition you already have no accesses to data members within that function.